# How to get JPG from string when it doesn't have http? php

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm struggling to do this when there are repeated specific characters, for instance:

```
$content = '<!CDATA[/2018/08/hello.jpg]]>{s:4:"file";s:7:"yes.jpg"';
```

I have only been able to find suggestions like this:

```
$pattern = '/(?:http|https):\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|jpeg)/';
preg_match_all ($pattern, $content, $matches);
```

which are always looking for http/https to know where to get it from, but in my case it is only partial urls and start/end with different characters - either `/x.jpg]` or `"x.jpg"`

Is it possible to find all .jpg images in a string composed of lots of examples like that? In this example it would find both hello.jpg and yes.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example data, you might use :

`<!CDATA\[.*?/\K\w+\.\jpg(?=\]\])`

**Explanation**

- `<!CDATA\[` Match `<!CDATA[`
- `.*?/` Match any character zero or more times non greedy and match a forward slash
- `\K` Forget was was previously matched
- `\w+\.\jpg` Match 1+ word characters followed by .jpg
- `(?=\]\])` Positive lookahead to assert what follows is ]]

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGfnEO/1)

```
$re = '@<!CDATA\[.*?/\K\w+\.\jpg(?=\]\])@';
$str = '<!CDATA[/2018/08/hello.jpg]]><!CDATA[/2018/08/another.jpg]]>';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/e9lgg)

Comment: Ah perfect that would work for that part, I just edited the question slightly as the string also contains jpgs in other ways that need extracting, apologies for not including it originally!

Comment: @Sometip But now you added `{s:4:"file";s:7:"yes.jpg"` to the end of the string. Is that the only .jpg that can match or can there be multiple as well?

Comment: It's a huge string with lots of jpg references, but they seem to either be surrounded by a /image.jpg] or "image.jpg" every time, I just added the extra surrounding parts in the example to illustrate how there are (for example in the first jpg types) multiple / so can't use that as the starting point of the regex, this is what's making it so tricky for me :/

Comment: I've simplified the question, as I think I overcomplicated the explanation, thanks for the help you've already given, really appreciate it!

Comment: Well if it is in a huge string and you are looking for those images, would this work for you? `/\K\w+\.jpg(?=\]\])|"\K\w+\.jpg(?=")` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGfnEO/2/) Then there is no logic which takes the cdata into account, but only if it is between `/` and `]]` or between double quotes.